# refer to Array pattern in scala

Tags: arrays, scala

```
val Array(direction, value, power, type, zone) = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Is there any way to refer Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) from some reference that we can use to perform other array operations like iterating array, etc..

i want to use direction, value, power, type, zone as they are more meaningful rather then using arr(0), arr(1), etc.. in addition to doing regular operations on array

Comment: Don't use an Array? Or make its contents into a case class as @irundaia suggests. "Doctor, it hurts when I do that..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your array as follows:

```
val arr @ Array(direction, value, power, t, zone) = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

This way you can use `arr` as a normal Array and the other "meaningful" vals.

Note that I changed `type` by `t` because the first one is a reserved word of the language.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the object to have meaningful accessors to the values it is containing, I would suggest to simply use a case class:

```
case class MyDataClass(direction: Int, values: Int, power: Int, type: Int, zone: Int)

val d = MyDataClass(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

val dir = d.direction
```

To use it as you would with a traditional array, I would add an implicit conversion to `Array[Int]`

Answer (score 1):

Store the array as normal, then `def` the elements as indexes into the array.

```
val array = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
def direction = array(0)
// etc.
```

This will still work inside of other methods as Scala allows methods in methods.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something here? Why not just do

```
val arr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`
```

and then subscript the individual elements (`arr(0)`, `arr(1)`, etc.) when you need them?

Comment: i want to use a, b, c, d, e as they are more meaningful rather then using arr(0), arr(1), etc.. in addition to doing regular opertions on array